# AJAX POST request - 405 Method not allowed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using JQuery AJAX to POST data to another endpoint. The endpoint I'm using is configured to accept CORs requests and I've managed to get it working with JQuery 3.3.1. However I continuously get the below error when attempting to use an older version of JQuery (1.7). I'm wondering if anyone could shed some light on what might be the issue. My code is here:

```
var token = getCookie('hubspotutk'); //Get the users cookie
    var pageTitle = document.title; //Title of page
    var pageURL = document.URL; //URL of page
    var submissionTime = new Date().getTime(); //Get time in milliseconds to record submission
    var formData = $(this).serializeArray(); //Get the form data and convert to an array
    var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(formData); //Convert the array to a JSON String

    //Define settings for AJAX request
    var settings = {
    "url": "https://api.hsforms.com/submissions/v3/integration/submit/xxxx/xxxxxx/", //FORM API ENDPOINT
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json","cache-control": "no-cache"},
    "data": `{
                "submittedAt": "` + submissionTime + `",
                "fields": ` + myJsonString + `,
                "context": {
                        "hutk": "` + token + `",
                        "pageUri": "` + pageURL +`",
                        "pageName": "` + pageTitle + `"
                    },
                "skipValidation": true
            }`
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response); //Output the response
    });
});
```

Error I get in console is here:

```
   GET https://api.hsforms.com/submissions/v3/integration/submit/xxx/xxxxxx/?{%22submittedAt%22:%20%221548857641912%22,%22fields%22:%20[],%22context%22:%20{%22hutk%22:%20%224db30dd95b30e746b4719cd94e0a0ae5%22,%22pageUri%22:%20%22http://www.test.com/form-testing-example-2?x%22,%22pageName%22:%20%22Form%20Testing%20Example%202%22},%22skipValidation%22:%20true} 405
form-testing-example-2?x:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.hsforms.com/submissions/v3/integration/submit/xxxx/xxxxxxx/?{%22submittedAt%22:%20%221548857641912%22,%22fields%22:%20[],%22context%22:%20{%22hutk%22:%20%224db30dd95b30e746b4719cd94e0a0ae5%22,%22pageUri%22:%20%22http://www.test.com/form-testing-example-2?x%22,%22pageName%22:%20%22Form%20Testing%20Example%202%22},%22skipValidation%22:%20true}' from origin 'http://www.test.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

It seems a GET request occurs despite me specifying a POST request in my code. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: **Don't ever** build JSON this way, this is going to break. Use `"data": JSON.stringify({...})` with an actual object.

Comment: i think the problem is you are accessing it from local or http, so you have this issue, https will fix it

Comment: or use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc) to change CORS

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare your data as an object and not as a string.

```
data: { ... }
```

instead of

```
data: '{ ... }'
```

Regards

Comment: you can also send it as string, you are nearly correct but i think his issue is its not proper string

Comment: I don't think this is the issue as I have it successfully submitting using JQuery 3.3. This issue only occurs on legacy versions of JQuery